# How to check for state of current call in Skpy module

Tags: python, skype

im trying to figure out how to check for the state of the current call in Skype

[Skpy Api Documentation](https://skpy.t.allofti.me/reference/api.html?highlight=call#skpy.msg.SkypeCallMsg)

> class skpy.msg.SkypeCallMsg[source]¶ A message representing a change
> in state to a voice or video call inside the conversation.
>
> state New state of the call.
>
> TYPE State
>
> users User objects embedded in the message.
>
> TYPE SkypeUser list
>
> userNames Names of the users, as seen by the initiator of the call.
>
> TYPE str list
>
> State = ('Started', 'Ended', 'Missed') Possible call states (either
> started and incoming, or ended).
>
> State.Started New call has just begun.
>
> State.Ended Call failed to connect, or all call participants have hung
> up.
>
> State.Missed Missed the call as it ended.
>
> TYPE SkypeEnum

something like `Skype.CallMsg.State == "Started"` doesnt work and i have no idea how to reference it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A state is an enum object with 3 values (Started, Missed, and Ended). To check if the call event has started, you use `event.msg.State.Started` (returns bool: either True or False).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but i can listen incoming calls with `SkypeEventLoop.onEvent()` and printing `event.msg.content`, im used value of the `event.msg.content`, when call incoming possible to print value of `event.msg.content`, that value can be much long, but i took the first 6 symbols to recognize call event in another values.

Comment: This is not an answer. You are welcome to comment on the question if you want to add to the conversation